# Cassandra phi_convict_threshold explained

Tags: cassandra

Can anyone point me to a good explanation of how is phi_convict_threshold calculated in cassandra (not the one from datastax documentation but more detailed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cassandra: The Definitive Guide, 2nd edition" has (IMHO) quite good description of it.  And it refers to original paper "[The φ accrual failure detector](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xavier_Defago/publication/29682135_The_ph_accrual_failure_detector/links/0a85e53ce412e3b069000000/The-ph-accrual-failure-detector.pdf)"